# Renomear os níveis de um fator baseado em um data frame

Tags: r, data.frame, dplyr

Suponha que eu tenha o data frame `iris`, presente na memória do R:

```
head(iris)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Suponha também que eu possua também um data frame chamado `flores`, com a seguinte estrutura:

```
flores <- data.frame(Especies=c("setosa", "virginica", "versicolor"), 
                     Nome=c("Flor 1", "Flor 2", "Flor 3"))
    Especies   Nome
1     setosa Flor 1
2  virginica Flor 2
3 versicolor Flor 3
```

Eu gostaria de substituir os ocorrências de `iris$Species` pelas de `flores$Nome`. Ou seja, eu gostaria que cada ocorrência de `setosa` em `iris$Species` fosse substituída por `Flor 1`; cada ocorrência de `virginica` em `iris$Species` fosse substituída por `Flor 2`; e cada ocorrência de `versicolor` em `iris$Species` fosse substituída por `Flor 3`.

Utilizar algo como `if` ou `ifelse` está fora de questão, pois o conjunto de dados com o qual estou trabalhando possui milhares de ocorrências de espécies diferentes. Seria impossível digitar todas as opções com as quais eu tenho que trabalhar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu faria um [`left_join`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html) e em seguida apagaria a variável. Por exemplo:

```
> library(dplyr)
> flores <- data.frame(Especies=c("setosa", "virginica", "versicolor"), 
+                      Nome=c("Flor 1", "Flor 2", "Flor 3"))
> 
> iris <- left_join(iris, flores, by = c("Species" = "Especies")) %>%
+   select(-Species) %>%
+   rename(Species = Nome)
> 
> head(iris)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  Flor 1
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  Flor 1
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  Flor 1
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  Flor 1
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  Flor 1
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  Flor 1
```

Usar [`case_when`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html) também poderia ser uma opção, mas não se você já tiver esse `data.frame` de nomes.

Em tempo, existe a função [`fct_recode`](http://forcats.tidyverse.org/reference/fct_recode.html) do pacote `forcats`:

Answer (score 5):

Creio que o código seguinte resolve a questão.
No entanto, tive uns problemas com as colunas envolvidas, porque são de classe `factor`. Em primeiro lugar, inclui o argumento `stringsAsFactors` na criação da data frame `flores`. E de seguida transformei a coluna `Species` em `character`.

```
flores <- data.frame(Especies=c("setosa", "virginica", "versicolor"), 
                     Nome=c("Flor 1", "Flor 2", "Flor 3"),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

iris$Species <- as.character(iris$Species)

for(s in unique(iris$Species)){
    iris$Species[iris$Species == s] <- flores$Nome[flores$Especie == s]
}

iris$Species <- factor(iris$Species)    # voltar a factor
```

Se a coluna `Nome` de `flores` tiver que ser `factor` então deverá usar

```
iris$Species[inx] <- as.character(flores$Nome[flores$Especie == s])
```

dentro do ciclo `for`.